# How to compute the logarithm of a computable number

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, computer-science, real-numbers

Let's say you have a [computable number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) $x>0$. $\ln(x)$ is computable as well. Given the computability of $x$, what is a computation for $\ln(x)$. I am using the definition where $a$ is computable if there is a computable function $f_a$ such that $$\frac{f_a(n)-1}n<a<\frac{f_a(n)+1}n$$
so my question becomes given $f_x$ how do you write an algorithm for $f_{\ln(x)}$.
If you like though, you can use any definition of computable number will do (so long as you use the same one for $x$ and $\ln(x)$.)

Comment: If $x$ is computable than there exists a sequence of rational numbers $\{q_i\}$ that converge to $x$, so the sequence $\{\log q_i\}$ converge to $\log x$.

Comment: @EmilioNovati But $\ln(q_i)$ is not rational.

Comment: Yes, but can be approximated by rationals with any given approximation.